# get an IO object from a link in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I want to write a method (in Ruby/Rails) that takes a URL (String) to a text file  and uses JSON to parse it.

# LOAD entity file
  def load (url)
`    result = JSON.parse(x)
  end

What should `x` be? (I know it needs to be either a String or an IO object, but how do I get a string/IO object whose content is the content of the file that `url` points to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'open-uri'

def load(url)
  open(url) do |file|
    JSON.parse(file.read)
  end
end
```

Comment: Just to be clear, `url` is acutally a string. Would this still work? OR does it have to be some object of some `Url` class?

Comment: Yes, a string for the url is expected.

Comment: Works for me! Thanks much! By the way, do you know where I can get information on what kind of object `JSON.parse` returns? (I'm new to Ruby!)

Comment: JSON.parse returns whatever Ruby objects are encoded in the string, E.g. JSON.parse({foo: :bar}.to_json).is_a?(Hash)